# Как работает ввод текста в терминале linux?

Tags: linux, консоль, unix

Всем привет, кто нибудь может объяснить хотя бы примерно, как работает ввод текста в терминале с клавиатуры?

Не получается нагуглить подобное да и не знаю даже как правильно сформулировать запрос. В общем, что именно
в линуксе занимается считыванием данных с клавиатуры и отображением их в терминале? Командные оболочки такие
как **bash** и **sh** насколько я знаю этим не занимаются. Они лишь принимают ввод из **stdin** и выполняют команды.

Допустим я написал какую-то программу на **С** и там прописал что-то типа *fgets(buffer, 20, stdin);*

И когда я выполняю эту программу, то на этой строчке терминал переходит в режим считывания данных с клавиатуры. Но как это работает не понятно. В **stdin** может быть как файл так и данные с клавиатуры. Это как-то на уровне ядра
происходит? Где система проверяет если **stdin** это файл, то просто считать данные из файла, а если это какое-то устройство
типа клавиатуры, то запустить какой нить процесс считывания с клавиатуры. Помогите плиз.

Comment: Тут есть ответ на английском, пример полностью подойдет. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312922/detect-if-stdin-is-a-terminal-or-pipe

Comment: большая часть (если не все) из выдвинутых вами гипотез не соответствуют окружающей действительности (нет у терминала никакого «режима считывания», в stdin могут быть только байты, никакой дополнительный процесс кроме вашего не запускается, ну и т.д. и т.п.). начните с [начала](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB) и далее [по списку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TTY-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) и ссылкам.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, вторая вроде то, что нужно. Вроде стало понятно, что редактированием вводимого текста занимается драйвер в ядре, а не отдельные программы. Понять бы еще как этот ввод включается. Я запускаю в терминале программу, она что-то выводит на экран, в этот момент я не могу печатать. Когда я начинаю читать данные из stdin, процесс останавливается и включается ввод. Я ввожу текст и нажимаю enter и введенная строка попадает в программу, выполнение продолжается. Программа не знает откуда эти данные пришли, из файла или с клавиатуры. Но в случае с клавиатурой кто-то включает ввод, но кто

Comment: если кто-то и «включает ввод» (на самом деле нет), то это делаете вы сами, с помощью той же упомянутой вами функции `fgets()`.

Comment: *в этот момент я не могу печатать* — кстати, вполне можете. кто ж вам помешает?

Comment: Спасибо, кажется разобрался. Печать действительно работает всегда. Просто некоторые программы насколько я узнал, могу переводить режим ввода в "сырой/неканоничный" и сами уже управляют вводом.

Answer (score 1):

> В stdin может быть как файл так и данные с клавиатуры. Это как-то на
>   уровне ядра происходит?

Процесс назначения *stdin* и *stdout* для конкретной программы не является "одноступенчатым". На самом деле, события развиваются как-то так:

1. Вы подходите к терминалу (их может быть **много** разных) и вводите логин/пароль.
2. Демон логина проверяет Ваши права и (если всё ОК) сообщает ядру о входе пользователя с Вашим конкретным ID.
3. Ядро, по ID ищет в файле */etc/passwd* информацию о Вас.
4. Найдя эту инфу, ядро устанавливает заданный для Вас текущий каталог и запускает тот варианта *shell*, который указан в Ваших данных. При запуске *shell* ему передаётся имя устройства */dev/tty...* с которого вы залогинились.

Это устройство становится *stdin* и *stdout* для Вашего экземпляра *shell*. Первая часть назначения завершена.  Дальше события развиваются следующим образом:

1. *shell* печатает на *stdout* приглашение ввода - промпт.
2. Вы печатает нечто вроде *my_prog* и нажимаете Enter.
3. *shell* считывает имя программы, и выполняет системные вызовы *fork* и *execve*.
4. Ядро выделяем память для процесса и копирует(!!!) туда всё программное окружение, включая (!) дескрипторы файлов *stdin* и *stdout*

Таким образом, Ваше приложение наследует в качестве стандартных устройств ввода/вывода тот самый терминал, с которого Вы залогинились. Но, возможно, что Ваша команда имеет вид:

```
 > my_prog < my_stdin.txt
```

Тогда *shell*, выполняя запуск Вашего приложения, проверит существование *my_stdin.txt*, откроет этот файл на чтение и передаст дескриптор этого уже открытого файла Вашему приложению на месте *stdin*.

Ваше приложение может выяснить, откуда оно выполняет ввод, с помощью системных вызовов как-то так:

```
struct stat *sb;

fstat(stdin, &sb);
if ((sb.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG) {
    /* обработка обычного файла */
}
```

Сам процесс ввода/выода для *stdin* выполняется **драйвером** соответствующего типа: терминала, дисковой файловой системы, СОМ-порта и т.д. Именно там выполняется необходимое буферирование, копирование и всё остальное. Прикладная программа имеет полное право совсем не знать, откуда идёт ввод.

Всё сказанное относится и к *stdout*.